# How to prevent gnome pop-ups when drive is (re)connected?

Tags: gnome, usb, android

MicroUSB cables are extremely finnicky when it comes to having all connectors having contact inside the microUSB female port on the phone.  Every time my phone moves even slightly when developing Android apps, my phone disconnects then reconnects, opening up a new gnome window or two. Believe it or not, this is not an issue with the phone, as it happens with multiple phones. It also happens with multiple microUSB cords. The hardware's disconnect/reconnect is not an Ubuntu issue, but the fact that there is an annoying pop-up of the disk contents every time it happens is an Ubuntu issue, especially since unlike a USB drive, I don't need to ever use a GUI for an android phone connection. I only need it to use with command line software like `adb` or third-party guis like `android-studio`

I still want my device to mount automatically, I just don't want gnome to issue a pop-up with its contents. Is there any way I can prevent myself from having to close 100 gnome windows after an hour of Android development?

The window is the usual file explorer, like what comes up when you run `gnome-open ./`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gsettings desktop schema controls whether to automatically open a folder for automounted media.

Citing directly from the source code:

> If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically open a folder when media is automounted. This only applies to media where no known x-content/* type was detected; for media where a known x-content type is detected, the user configurable action will be taken instead.

This gsetting can be modified with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

*This setting does not modify the automount behaviour. The automount is controlled by the `automount` option).*

*(the information for this answer was pulled from the [Gnome source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.gschema.xml.in))*

Answer (score 5):

Go to *Settings* → *Devices* → *Removable Media* → check *Never prompt or start programs on media insertion*.

[image: Removable media settings]

Answer (score 0):

## Uses `disks` utility to never show mounted drive

Start `Dash` the first option on the `Launcher`

Type `Disks` and you will see the application `Disks` appear. Click on it.

A screen similar to this appears:

[image: Open Disks]

Left click on a Disk. Then left click on the Partition you want to hide.

Right click on the gear (follows the Left Arrow and `-`) and select `Edit Mount Options` and this screen appears:

[image]

Uncheck the option `Show in User Interface`.

Click OK and enter password to apply changes. After the next reboot Nautilus won't show the partition. Note that this doesn't erase the partition or delete any data on it.

The phone will still automatically mount and unmount, however it will not appear in the User Interface. This will hopefully remove the annoying popup windows you are receiving.

---

## For faulty phone jacks

Generically speaking, if a new cable doesn't solve the problem then I think you need to resolder the USB jack onto the PCB:

- [How do I solder this USB Connector?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68917/how-do-i-solder-this-usb-connector)

[image]